# Array data extraction

Tags: javascript, json, api

*Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question.*

One problem only? But there is only one problem! 
I am trying to extract a single specific JSON value

```
{"atcocode":"40004409095B","smscode":"surdgwtj","request_time":"2019-12-15T13:16:41+00:00","name":"Reigate Railway Station (Stop B)","stop_name":"Reigate Railway Station","bearing":"S","indicator":"Stop B","locality":"Reigate","location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.20506,51.24182]},"departures":{"460":[{"mode":"bus","line":"460","line_name":"460","direction":"Crawley, Bus Station","operator":"METR","date":"2019-12-15","expected_departure_date":null,"aimed_departure_time":"14:04","expected_departure_time":null,"best_departure_estimate":"14:04","source":"NextBuses","dir":"inbound","operator_name":"Metrobus","id":"https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/route/METR/460/inbound/40004409095B/2019-12-15/14:04/timetable.json?app_id=6116c297\u0026app_key=6f8080ec4ed509a3c87a8a19e40dcc5d"}],"420":[{"mode":"bus","line":"420","line_name":"420","direction":"Crawley, Bus Station","operator":"METR","date":"2019-12-15","expected_departure_date":null,"aimed_departure_time":"15:04","expected_departure_time":null,"best_departure_estimate":"15:04","source":"NextBuses","dir":"inbound","operator_name":"Metrobus","id":"https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/route/METR/420/inbound/40004409095B/2019-12-15/15:04/timetable.json[API KEY REDACTED]
```

```
onst { atcocode, stop_name, smscode} = data;

    document.getElementById('sn').textContent = stop_name;
    document.getElementById('atcd').textContent = atcocode;
    document.getElementById('sms').textContent = smscode;
    document.getElementById('edt').textContent = data.departures[460][0].expected_departure_time;
    document.getElementById('rte').textContent = data.departures[460][0].line;
```

What is the correct syntax to make the time show correctly.

Comment: which time? there are more than one time properties.

Comment: Any of them, it's only for testing / learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` and `time` properties are further nested inside the data, so you need additional object and array destructuring to access them.

```
const { atcocode, stop_name, smscode, departures} = data;
const  [{ line }]  = departures[460];                   //or departures[420], whichever you want
const  [{ aimed_departure_time }]  = departures[460];   ////or departures[420], whichever you want
```

Comment: That works just fine, thank you.  I think my mistake was in trying to put everything into one ```const ```

Comment: Please add further information about what this code does instead of just writing the code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should get value as an associative array `data.departures[420][0]['line']` .Check the solution.

```
     const { atcocode, stop_name, smscode} = data;

     let ep_time_460 = data.departures[460][0]['expected_departure_time'];
     let rte_460 = data.departures[460][0]['line'];

     console.log(ep_time_460+"--"+rte_460);

     let ep_time_420 = data.departures[420][0]['expected_departure_time'];
     let rte_420 = data.departures[420][0]['line'];

     console.log(ep_time_420+"--"+rte_420);
```

Comment: This solution works too. I've no idea which is best to use going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `departures[460]` where the property is a number (`460`). In the provided json the property is a string though. Therefore you need to access it as such: `departures['460']`.